# wordpress contact form 7 and custom jQuery conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 on wordpress and untill today I have experienced a problem. I have come to learn that it is a jQuery conflict. I find the problem only occurs in chrome works fine in firefox.

I have some custom jQuery which I placed in which can be seen below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function(){
        var map = [ '11.99', '£13.99', '£14.99' ];

        jQuery('#payslips-required').change(function(){
            var o = parseInt($(this).val()) < 3 ? jQuery(this).val()-1 : 2;
            jQuery('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
        });
    });
</script>
```

With the above in place the ajax does not work on contact form 7 which I require. When I remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works but the custom jQuery does not. I need both to run.

This is the error I get when I inspect it in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing in the code posted that would require a three year old jQuery version to make it run ?

Comment: if that was the case why does it not work when I remove it?

Comment: How should I know, it works perfectly fine for me in all versions of jQuery -> http://jsfiddle.net/3wsHA/ ... so that's not the issue.

Comment: I've done the same and still have the same issue their is still a conflict which is causing contact form 7 to loose its ajax function. Is it possible that because their are two jquery being called its causing one to override the other?

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't load two versions of jQuery, and that's why I noted that the code posted above should work in all versions of jQuery, and you should be using the newest version. In fact, in wordpress you should never include jQuery by hardcoding it in, you should use enqueue script() to handle that for you.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? new to wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the call to the old JQUERY file. Then move your custom  lines to be below where Wordpress is calling the JQUERY file. Most likely your  is running before the JQUERY js file is loaded.

Comment: Hi Joe I have tried this still the same result. Ajax works custom jquery does not. Here what it looks like http://builtbyaddy.com/header.txt hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
define ('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false );
```

in your config file. Please [see this](http://ideasilo.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/contact-form-7-1-10/) for further reference.

Comment: Please ensure that you copy and paste the relevant part of the background information from this link into your answer.

Comment: work fine, here the ufficial documentation of CF7:
https://contactform7.com/controlling-behavior-by-setting-constants/